# Plotting whole month in python with only 1 day data

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot with an amount (int) in the y-axis and days in the x-axis.
I want the plot to always have the whole month in the x-axis although I dont have data for all days.
This is the code I tryed:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

df=get_pandas_data(datab) #Taking data from database in pandas DataFrame

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) #Initialize plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

dates=[dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for d in df['date']]
dates=list(set(dates)) #Takes all the dates from de Dataframe and sets to avoid repeated dates

s=df.resample('D', on='date')['amount'].sum() #Takes the total amount for the same date

ax1.bar(dates,s) #Bar plot for dates and amount 

ax1.set(xlabel="Date",
   ylabel="Balance (€)",
   title="Total Monthly balance") # Plot information

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')) 
#this is soposed to set all days of the month in the x-axis
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

The result I get from this is a plot but only with those days that have data.
How can I make the plot to have all days in the month and plot the bar on those who have data?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine with bare datetimes and matplotlib so you must be malforming your data somehow when doing your pandas manipulations.  But we can't really help because we don't have your dataframe.  Its always preferable to create a standalone example with dummy data, and as little code as possible to recreate the issue.  a) 90% of the time you will realize your problem b) if not, we can help...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime 
x = np.array([1, 3, 7, 8, 10])
y = x * 2

dates = [datetime.datetime(2000, 2, xx) for xx in x]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(dates, y)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: Bars with dates]